# How can I apply a pattern to an SVG element that ignores the element's transform values?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have a JavaScript application that modifies an inline SVG. I have multiple elements within the SVG that all need to have the same background image applied to them. Elements (paths) are positioned in the SVG via transform attributes. Presently I am using a pattern fill on the elements. Is there any way to achieve the effect of the pattern staying stationary irrespective to element transforms?

Currently I have this:

[image: seamed background]

I want this:
[image: seamless background]

(note: I hard-baked the path in the second photo, which can't be used in the application)

Edit:

The patterns are currently applied like so:

```
<defs>
    <pattern id="metallicgold" x="0" y="0" width="1240" height="775" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <image xlink:href="img/gold-texture.png" />
    </pattern>
</defs>
```

The transforms on elements look like this:

```
<path transform="translate(-445.0000396775016 -1950.3326958481455) rotate(317.2309439443859 2926.326416015625 2926.32666015625) scale(1 1)" style="fill: url('#metallicgold'); stroke: none;" d="M1951.326416015625,1951.32666015625L3901.326416015625,1951.32666015625L3901.326416015625,3901.32666015625L1951.326416015625,3901.32666015625L1951.326416015625,1951.32666015625Z" x="0" y="0"></path>
```

Comment: Could you show us some code?

Comment: @Rojo sure thing

Comment: Have you tried playing with `transform-origin` ?

Comment: Can we get an [mcve] here i.e. something complete we can run ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a constant background as you transform shapes, you should consider using a filter with userSpaceOnUse filterUnits, unless the transforms are easy and apply to all elements filled, in which case, you can use patternTransform on the pattern to reverse the transform on the elements.

```html
<svg width="800px" height="600px" viewBox="0 0 4000 4000">
  
  <defs>
    <filter id="brick" x="0" y="0" width="4000" height="4000" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <feImage xlink:href="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/c9/97/81/c99781a0ab356681cb038f70b1df68f1.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="4000" height="4000" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"/>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
</defs>
  

  
  <g filter="url(#brick)">
  <path transform="translate(-445.00 -1950.33) rotate(317.23 2926.32 2926.32) scale(1 1)"  stroke="none" fill="red" d="M1951.326416015625,1951.32666015625L3901.326416015625,1951.32666015625L3901.326416015625,3901.32666015625L1951.326416015625,3901.32666015625L1951.326416015625,1951.32666015625Z" x="0" y="0"></path>
  </g>
  
    <rect x="1250" y="500" width="300" height="300" fill="blue"/>
  
    <g filter="url(#brick)">
  <circle cx="1000" cy="1000" r="500"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
```